# Do you know repositories which have datasets of open data about public trasport services?

Tags: json, csv, dataset, splunk, opendata

I am in need of free datasets or Web repositories which contain open data (no private data) in order to build vizualisations with Splunk Enterprise.

Any suggestions?

Thanks a lot,
Skender

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jeremy Singer-Vine's [Data Is Plural](http://tinyletter.com/data-is-plural) mailing list had a few public transit datasets a couple weeks ago:

- [Washington DC Metro data](https://github.com/bizweekgraphics/wmata-ridership-data) for days of recent presidential inaugurations and protests.
- [New York MTA turnstile data](http://web.mta.info/developers/turnstile.html)
- [Chicago Transit Authority el-train ridership](https://data.cityofchicago.org/Transportation/CTA-Ridership-L-Station-Entries-Daily-Totals/5neh-572f)

Hope that helps!